# Volley. Sending JSONObject as parameter

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i have googled and looked into other SO articles. but none helped. Please help me identify what is the problem. What i did was i want to change from `StringRequest` to `JsonObjectRequest`

I am getting this error:

```
com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

**MY CODE**

```
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "http://"+employee.get_ip_address()+"/NextrackAndroid/authenticate.php";
    Log.d("TAG", "URL : "+ url);

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        obj.put("id", id.toString());
        obj.put("deviceID", deviceID.toString());
        Log.d("TAG", obj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,obj,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onResponse : " + response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("TAG", "onErrorResponse : " + error.toString());
                    error.printStackTrace();
                }
            }){
        /** Passing some request headers* */
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            return headers;
        }
    };
    queue.add(jsObjRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

This is not your side issue. 
This issue persist when your response is not a `JSONObject`. So your code can not handle it. Because you have taken `JsonObjectRequest` as response handler.

To overcome this issue.

- Check its response on [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) or ask from Web Service developer.
- You will find the response of Web-Service is not perfect JSON.
- Then ask Web-Service developer to fix this issue.
- **Or change your `JsonObjectRequest` to `StringRequest` if response is not JSON from server side.**

Comment: Thank you so much. I searched in so many stack overflow articles, nobody mentioned that the issue exist in the response from server. I thought something was wrong with my code.

Comment: Yes, i did. Thanks to you